# Convert multiple .sav to .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, spss

I want to convert a bunch of `.sav` to `.csv`

I have a list of files like this:

`c("Congo_MICS5_Datasets/Congo MICS 2014-15 SPSS Datasets/bh.sav", "Congo_MICS5_Datasets/Congo MICS 2014-15 SPSS Datasets/ch.sav", "Congo_MICS5_Datasets/Congo MICS 2014-15 SPSS Datasets/hh.sav")`

How do i convert them and keep the file name?

Comment: _"keep the filename"_? i.e. `bh.csv`, `ch.csv`, `hh,.csv`?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're in the working directory that can access the relative paths and assuming you're using the `foreign` package and assuming you don't want row names (lots of assumptions since the question  is sparse):

```
c(
  "Congo_MICS5_Datasets/Congo MICS 2014-15 SPSS Datasets/bh.sav", 
  "Congo_MICS5_Datasets/Congo MICS 2014-15 SPSS Datasets/ch.sav", 
  "Congo_MICS5_Datasets/Congo MICS 2014-15 SPSS Datasets/hh.sav"
) -> fils

for (fil in fils) {

  write.csv(
    x = foreign::read.spss(file = fil, to.data.frame = TRUE),
    file = sprintf("%s.csv", tools::file_path_sans_ext(fil)),
    row.names = FALSE
  )

}
```

Comment: That works, but you missed an s off in the for loop bit

Comment: can't run the code b/c i thankfully don't have SPSS data :-) if you have edit privs (not sure what point val that kicks in) pls make that change (I'm not seeing where the `s` is missing) and I can approve the edit.